# Python 3 multi-threading with return from thread not running parallely

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x

I am trying to run following code of threading.

```
import Queue
import threading

def get_items(url):
    print(url)
    #Do some stuff with print here
    return url.split()

q = Queue.Queue()
urls = [LIST OF URLS]

for u in urls[:10]:
    t = threading.Thread(target=get_items, args=(q, u))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

this should run the threads in parallel but it is running it sequentially. Secondly, how can I append value of thread's return statement in a list.?

Answer (score 0):

My code run successfully when I did following changes in it.

```
import Queue
import threading

def get_items(q, url):
    print(url)
    #Do some stuff with print here
    q.put(url.split())

q = Queue.Queue()
urls = [LIST OF URLS]

for u in urls[:10]:
    t = threading.Thread(target=get_items, args=(q, u))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    th.append(t)

for t in th:
    t.join()

print(q.get())
```